# How can I change jquery mobile select menu button background color based to selection?

Tags: jquery-mobile

How can I change jquery mobile select menu button background color based to selection?

Below is my code so far. It only changes option value background color but not select menu button background color.

```
<select id="colormenu" data-mini="true" >
<option value="red">red</option>
<option value="green">green</option>
<option value="blue">blue</option>
<option value="black">black</option>
</select>   


$("#colormenu").css("background-color", $(this).val())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure what you *exact* problem is, but this illustrates with your code how you can change the background color of the select element from its value. Maybe you got the event wrong?

```
$(function() { //document load event
    $("#colormenu").change(function() { //change event of element
        $(this).css("background-color", $(this).val())
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/08e77sr9/

EDIT: Or maybe the code you posted was the only code you had? Then the explanation is that you have to hook the code up to the elements chage event. And that needs to be done when the document has loaded

EDIT: The solution is this, you need to target the right element, jquery mobile generates a lot of new elements:

```
$("#colormenu-button").css("background-color", $(this).val())
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9xkx46up/

Comment: Your example works without jquery mobile. I have updated fiddle with jquery mobile(external resource). Please see http://jsfiddle.net/08e77sr9/2/

Comment: @user3189644 Okay, so jquery-mobile was the problem. That generates a lot of new elements for styling, so you need to target the correct one (#colormenu-button). See the bottom of my post for the correct answet and working JSFiddle